# automatically fill field name in fe_users

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Is there a possibility to automatically fill the field "name" in fe_users from the entries in "first_name" and "last_name"?

Is it possible to configure femanager to fill this field in the background when the user is editing the fields first_name and last_name. Background is, that i need this field with a value in the extension seminars.

Thanks!

Comment: what version of TYPO3 are you using? Does the user fill the first_name and last_name in frontend or in backend?

Comment: TYPO3 9. the user fills first_name and last_name in the frontend with extension femanager.